# Can i fetch a tensor when i am using slim.learning.train?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-slim

Thanks for TF-Slim, it is easier to build new models

But when comes about training the model, it seems that slim.learning.train can't fetch a tensor which i need to check my model.

It can only return the loss (the training op), the code below is in tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py, it shows how loss is printed.

```
if sess.run(train_step_kwargs['should_log']):
  logging.info('global step %d: loss = %.4f (%.3f sec/step)',
               np_global_step, total_loss, time_elapsed)
```

Is there some ways to fetch a tensor or just print the value of it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have tensor `t`, then you can print it every time a graph is executed that involves using `t` by associating the tensor with a `tf.Print()` print function as follows:

`t = tf.Print(t, [t])`